# App crashes after clicking on setting before the content is loaded

Tags: java, android

My app crashes or goes back to home screen when someone click twice on settings in exo player, pressing it once shows " Please wait for the content to load " toast but pressing it twice crashes the app, although after the content is loaded the app doesn't crash, you can click on it as many times as you want. how do I solve it?

```
ImageView img_audio = findViewById(R.id.img_audio);
    img_audio.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        if (contentLoaded) {
            MappingTrackSelector.MappedTrackInfo mappedTrackInfo;
            DefaultTrackSelector.Parameters parameters = trackSelector.getParameters();
            TrackSelectionDialog trackSelectionDialog =
                    TrackSelectionDialog.createForTrackSelector(
                            trackSelector,
                            /* onDismissListener= */ dismissedDialog -> {
                            });
            trackSelectionDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), null);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(DetailsActivity.this, R.string.please_wait, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        // Active playback.
        contentLoaded = true;
      });
```

[image]

Comment: Add the crash stacktrace with question

Comment: Please do not edit your question to rewrite it to a solution. If you managed to solve your problem, that is great, but if you want to share your solution, you need to post an **answer**, not edit your **question**.

Comment: Thank you! I'll do that next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably from setting the condition to true, on the first click.
Then on the second click, it tries to access the content, which is not loaded.
Or why is the content for sure loaded, when the event was fired once?

```
// Active playback.
contentLoaded = true;
```

Comment: What do I change so that it doesn't try to access the content on the second or more clicks and wait for the content to load and keep showing the toast untill the content is loaded?!

Comment: Remove that // Active playback.
        contentLoaded = true;

Comment: after removing Active playback. contentLoaded = true, when the content is loaded it keeps showing the toast and not showing what the settings is supposed to show. Like changing the audio and the quality of the video etc.

Comment: I don´t know, you would have to show an [**reprex**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  . I believe you´re fundamentally missunderstanding something. The condition should be set from somewhere else in the code, when the loading of the content is done, so that it does not run into an nullPointerExecption, which is not caught and causes a crash. If you are not setting the condition to true somewhere else, than its true, it will never show the settings.

Comment: Where do you have the code example from?

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, the error has been solved <3

Comment: You were right, I had to set the condition to true somewhere else which solved the error :)

Comment: Glad, that i could help :)